# Wifi Problems with Acer Aspire E15 575G Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, atheros, aspire

[wireless-info here](http://pastebin.com/mprdqQEk)

I've noticed the following problems in my wi-fi:

1. Wi-fi is sometimes slow or doesn't connect to the usual spot after waking from suspend mode.
2. Internet speed only reaches 2mbps (compared to the dual-booted Windows installation which reaches 10mbps)
3. Wi-fi is very slow sometimes, even timing out some pages.

This only happens in the Ubuntu installation, as the wifi connection to my phone and when tried on Windows are working fine.

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu so appreciate any guidance and steps I can do to resolve this. Thanks!

(I've viewed some similar posts about this, it didn't help solve my issue at all)

**UPDATE:** I tried sitting beside the router then doing speedtest -- the speed bumped up considerably (almost near the speeds I achieve in Win10) -- any possible cause?

Comment: At your router, change the wireless encryption settings to WPA2-AES only, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode (your current setting) and certainly not TKIP (also your current setting). This will improve connection to all. The current devices that work acceptably with your current settings will work the same or better.

Comment: The above notwithstanding, you may have other issues with that Atheros driver but you need to do the aforementioned changes before any further troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks @CelticWarrior for the suggestion. Unfortunately my internet provider has locked up access to the router. Would you have any other troubleshooting suggestions? Worst case, I'll have to call them to change this setting.

Comment: This settings should be enough but if not their the starting point.

Comment: Ok thanks! Will do this and update the thread as soon as there's progress.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I've requested the change, hopefully it takes effect soon. One question in the meantime though, does 16.04 (or its drivers) not handle Wifi that well when it's WPA/WPA2/TKIP, causing the issues? Just wondering because in Win10, I don't have this issue at all and I get stable max speed.

Answer (score 1):

I would disable the power management for wifi with this in terminal

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot

I would agree with CelticWarrior about disabling TKIP if disabling the power management doesn't completely fix the issue